# HTTP authentication with PHP error after introduce the login

Tags: php, ldap, http-authentication

I need a code to Authenticate a user using LDAP. My code works, however if I miss the password or the user in the login fields I can not ask for authentication again, and i have to restart the browser so that it is possible to re-authenticate.

Can you help me please?

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
    header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    else{ 


    #Login request
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="test"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Login to acess';
        exit; 
    }

    $userAD = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $passAD = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    }
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to what is relevant only. Who knows, this way you may even solve the problem yourself. Learn to debug.

Comment: Done a need a condition to repeat the request to login.

Comment: Actually, can I see the whole code you placed the first time?  Rather than re-edit your question, put it into pastebin.com, a popular medium used in conjunction with this site, and link to it from here.  I love authentication problems and will try to reproduce/resolve it.